# Shortest PHP code for $i = $i + $x;

Tags: php

Im trying to learn a few shorter ways of doing things in php

Is there a shorter way of adding a number to a variable

in this case the code i want to shorten is: `$num = $num + rand(1000, 100);`

eg:

```
$num = 0;
        $count = 10;
        $i = 0;

        while ($i < $count) {
            $num = $num + rand(1000, 100);
            echo"$num<br/>";
            $i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `+=`

```
$num += rand(1000, 100);
```

Comment: And for completeness, you can do this with other operators as well, i.e. `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `.=`. The last one is quite handy when concatenating loads of things.

Answer (score -1):

You said you want to learn "a few shorter ways of doing things in php".
Well, there is a quicker way to add one to a variable.

```
// You can use $i+1
$i = 1;
$i = $i + 1

// Or $x++
$x = 1;
$x++;

// Now, if we echo this out we will get the same result from using $i+1 or $x++
echo $i;
echo $x;
```

Comment: However, `$i + 1` returns the value and `$i++` increments the value of the variable. Two very different things.